# C++11 strategy for adoption and compatability?

Tags: c++, c++11

We have libraries that only support or are tested with older versions of compilers e.g. visual stuidos 2010 sp1. but I want to start using C++11 feature. What is the safest pattern to use so I can ensure there is backward compatibility with old compilers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to test your code with older compilers, too. Sometimes you can use C++11 features like variadic templates to create a second code path that is easier to read and with better compiler error messages.

Obviously you are limited to features that are supported by the older compilers, too. For that lists with supported features like the one from [Apache wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) are helpful. When you drop support for older compilers you can use more and more features. That's the pattern I use.